# Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=)

Tags: facebook, https, file-get-contents

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-                get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /var/www/dsg/signed_request.php on line 25
```

I have checked and set allow_url_fopen to on in my php.ini and also made sure allow_url_fopen is on when I run phpinfo();. I am still getting the error as listed above. Does anyone know if this can be made to work somehow? Perhaps has some converted to an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl, which is actually what should be used for network requests, not file_get_contents. I don't know why Facebook started using that function in there examples. Curl has error handling and will follow redirects if you want it to, so you can figure out exactly what is happing.

Comment: I am using curl now. Now I am getting an error.An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: So you are communicating fine then. You need to start a session to get an access token to include in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own one line function like this

```
function viacurl($location){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $location);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    $out=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return rtrim($out,1);
}
```

And use it like this :

```
$response = viacurl($url);
```